# insert 300,000 record in cassandra by java loop

Tags: java, cassandra

I have 300,000 insert query in file and i want read query and insert record in cassandra with java language. like following

```
public class Main {
    static Cluster cluster =    
    Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
    static Session session = cluster.connect("test");
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader("the-file-name.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String sCurrentLine;
        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            session.execute(sCurrentLine);
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time1);
    }
}
```

But after running the program, i query following statement in cqlsh it returns 7200 in result

```
cqlsh:test> select count(*) from climate;

 count
-------
  7200

(1 rows)

Warnings :
Aggregation query used without partition key
```

My table definition is:

```
cqlsh:test> desc climate

CREATE TABLE test.climate (
    city text,
    date text,
    temprature int,
    time text,
    PRIMARY KEY (city, date)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: What does your table definition look like?  PRIMARY KEYS in Cassandra are unique.  I have seen this happen when devs try to write 4 different rows to the same PRIMARY KEY, and then wonder why they only have one row.

Comment: i added table definition @Aaron

Comment: Also, if you really did have 300k rows in that table, I would not be surprised if a `SELECT COUNT(*)` timed out.  Cassandra doesn't do well with unbound queries.

Comment: thanks @Aaron. I change primary key to  PRIMARY KEY ((city, date), time)